# I have a few amateur, naive questions about the Banach-Tarski decomposition.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I have a few amateur, naive questions about the Banach-Tarski decomposition. Let’s take a unit sphere (B1), and perform the decomposition so that we have a new sphere with twice the volume (B2). I realize that this transformation involves the use of the axiom of choice, and that B2 is composed of non-measurable sets.

1. If B2 is not measurable, what is the meaning of the “twice the volume” statement?
2. Let’s assume the B1 is the standard closed unit ball. It is certain characteristics. It is measurable, it is a metric space, and locally homeomorphic to R^3. Topologically, B1 is compact, locally compact, and paracompact. It is connected, simply connected, locally connected, path- and arc- connected. Which of these characteristics change when considering B2?

I imagine there is a bijective mapping from B1 to B2. I also suppose B2 is a Vitali set.

Thank you!

Comment: $B_2$ is measurable (it is a sphere, after all). What is not measurable are the $7$ or so pieces of $B_1$ that $B_2$ is made of.

Comment: As above, $B_2$ is a sphere, so it has all the nice qualities of a sphere you list in 2, and yes,  spheres are homeomorphic.  The weirdness comes in the breaking it up into pieces and looking at the pieces as objects in and of themselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing changes between $B_1$ and $B_2$ really. The statement of Banach-Tarski is (in the formulation I learnt from Stan Wagon's book *The Banach-Tarski paradox*): let $A,B$ be two bounded subsets of $\Bbb R^3$ both with non-empty interior. Then $A$ and $B$ are equi-decomposable ($A = \bigcup_{I=1}^n A_i$ and $B = \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$ where $n \in \Bbb N$ and for each $i$ we have a linear map $g_i \in SO_3$ (a rotation even) so that $g_i[A_i]=B_i$).

So your question is about when we take two balls of different volumes, but the volumes have nothing to do with a measure per se; the old Greeks already knew the formula for computing the volume of a sphere from its radius, $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$. But the above theorem allows us to have one sphere $B_1$, and cut it up in finitely many pieces using AC (so very non-constructively) and transform (rotate etc) those pieces and take the union of the transformed ones and get another sphere with larger radius(or smaller radius, if you like; or build two disjoint spheres or a cube etc.)

It's the *pieces* that are strange, not the end results. Your $B_1$ and $B_2$ are just homeomorphic and topologically indistinguishable. Banach showed in essence that the group of 3d-rotations is "weird" (or as Wagon calls it "paradoxical"). The relation with measures is that is shows that under AC there can be no finitely additive measure on $\Bbb R^3$ that measures all subsets and is rotation invariant while having the volume of a sphere have the known value. So it's not a paradox in that sense, it's just counterintuitive. Read Wagon's book to really understand Banach-Tarski, it's very good IMO.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: "It's the pieces that are strange." So, do theses pieces, on their own, have any interesting characteristics, topological or otherwise?

Comment: @BarnabyFinch Wagon discusses this in his book, about whether they can be Borel sets or analytic etc. Much is open there.